# how can I delete a row in Sqlite with foreign key?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a problem trying to delete a row from my db...
the DB looks like that:
[The DB picture][image: 1]

I want do delete a user so I tried:

```
DELETE FROM USERS WHERE ID = 201;
```

but obviously it didn't work out at all because it connects with the other TABLES.
And I cant use DROP because its sqlite.
I look up on the internet and got nothing...

the error:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2biP.png)

Comment: Look up "cascading foreign key references".  Then you need to decide what you want to do.  The *wrong* thing is to delete the row and have other tables refer to a non-existent row.

Comment: I want to Delete only 1 value. i have a list of users and i want only the id = 201 to be deleted. i looked it up already and it didn't help much...

Comment: And what about the rows that refer to that user?

Comment: what do you mean? i just want to delete 1 user, thats all... im looking from the sql code

Comment: Look at table `Albums` (for example). It has a field `USER_ID` (foreign key) which I assume refers to the user owning the album.  This means that you can't delete a user that owns child records until you have deleted all it's children.  @GordonLinoff says look up _"cascading foreign key references"_

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have another table that defines the `user_id` as a foreign key:

```
create table another (
    another_id int,
    user_id int,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

And you have data in this table, such as:

```
another_id    user_id
    1           200
    2           201
    3           201
```

Now, you want to delete 201 from users.  What happens to rows 2 and 3 in this table?  There are several options:

1. The rows remain with the values as is.  But those values no longer refer to a valid user.
2. The rows that refer to 201 are deleted.
3. The rows are set to some value, such as `NULL` or a default value.

The default behavior *without a foreign key constraint* is (1).  And you end up with dangling references.  And your database lacks relational integrity.  That is considered a bad thing.

SQL supports cascading delete and update foreign key references (although not all databases support these).  These respectively implement (2) and (3) on the above list.

You can also manually change the referring rows so the user can be deleted.  It is not clear what you really want to do, but this explains why you can't just delete the row and the facilities that SQL offers to get around that.

Comment: thank you for your comment! i want the second option to happend. and im not sure what to do

Comment: @prayerShawl . . . You need to define the foreign key as a cascading delete foreign key reference.  I would recommend that you start by reviewing the documentation:  https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html.

Comment: i tried to delete from the other table but it didn't work... its says the same error

Comment: @prayerShawl . . . That is why these are called "cascading".  The table you are deleting from in turn has a references to it.  And so on.  You are learning a lot today.